# Define a generic function type to support any number of args with any type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

In typescript we can define a function type like:

```
type FunctionHandler = {
   (param1: string, param2: number): string
}
```

But I want to declare a generic type that can take any number of params with their type as we do in variable typings like following:

```
type Variable<Props> = {
   [p in keyof Props]: Props[p]
}
```

I want something like:

```
type FunctionHandler<Props> = {
   ([p in keyof Props]: Props[p]): void | boolean
}
```

But I am not able to do it, can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is the input type and the expected output type.

Comment: I have two functions. One of them takes one string as argument, another one takes two. Both the function return boolean as return value. So what I want is to declare a generic type from which I can build type for each function just by passing what type I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rest param like so to have the function accept any number of arguments of any type:

```js
type FunctionHandler = {
  (...params: any): string
}
```

**See also**

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
type FunctionHandler<TArgs extends any[]> = (...params: TArgs) => void;
```

Or, an even more generic type, including the return type:

```
type FunctionHandler<TArgs extends any[], TReturn extends any> = (...params: TArgs) => TReturn;
```

Usage:

```
function doSomthingWithHandler(handler: FunctionHandler){
  const result = handler(123); // result will be of type `string`
}

doSomthingWithHandler((arg: number) => 'some string');
```